# CSS Border/Outline With Outside Padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a reusable div css class that I can use to highlight quotes in articles I am writing on my campaign website. When debugging in Visual Studio using Chrome (or Firefox) I get the desired result:

[image: Picture of Desired Look]

As you can see there is a silver border, but padding around it.

My CSS class is:

```
.articleQuote {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: navy;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: silver;
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, in Internet Explorer no padding on the border occurs. Seems like outline-offset is ignored.

[Link to article on my website](http://perry2018.com/news/articles/TD_MedicalMarijuana.aspx)

How can I get a cross-browser class set up that will produce the desired result?

Comment: In the code above you use a negative offset (`outline-offset: -10px;`). On your live website you use a positive offset (`outline-offset: 10px;`).

Comment: I see. When I published (via Visual Studio), it must not have updated the CSS file.  I manually replaced it now.  Google / Chrome now working. Still have issue with IE. Will revise question. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidP Looks like IE doesn't support `outline-offset`. See my answer for an alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outline-offset` is not supported in Internet Explorer.

You could use a combination of `outline` and `border` to achieve the same effect.

Here `border` is used for the silver line and `outline` is used for the white space surrounding the element.

```css
body {
  background: #fffacf;
  padding: 15px;
}

.articleQuote {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: navy;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: white;
  outline-width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="articleQuote">
  "80% of North Carolinians polled were in favor of legalizing medical marijuana in the state."
</div>
```

---

Another option is to use `box-shadow` instead of border or outline. This allows you to have as many "borders" as you like.

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 15px;
}

.articleQuote {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: navy;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px silver,
              0 0 0 10px white;
}

.crazy-border {
  margin: 50px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red,
              0 0 0 4px white,
              0 0 0 6px orange,
              0 0 0 8px white,
              0 0 0 10px gold,
              0 0 0 12px white,
              0 0 0 14px green,
              0 0 0 16px white,
              0 0 0 18px blue,
              0 0 0 20px white,
              0 0 0 22px purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="articleQuote">
  "80% of North Carolinians polled were in favor of legalizing medical marijuana in the state."
</div>

<div class="articleQuote crazy-border">
  "80% of North Carolinians polled were in favor of legalizing medical marijuana in the state."
</div>
```

Comment: Looks really cool. I updated the CSS on the website with your code and it does work in all browsers.  Only fault I see is that the div now hugs very closely to the <p> blocks before and after it.  Anyway to deal with that?

Comment: Unlike `border`, `outline` doesn't take up any space in the layout so you may need to add top and bottom margin to `.articleQuote` in order to create the needed space. eg. `margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;`

Comment: Looks good.  I added a width, and left-margin, right-margin to stop it from ballooning a bit to the left and the right.  Added new css to website. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try nested divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="article-quote-outer">
  <div class="article-quote-inner">
    {text goes here}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article-quote-outer {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.article-quote-inner {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Example:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tj12r4ao/6/)

Comment: If I have to use nested divs, I will. But hoping for a one div solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the desired result is no white space surrounding the silver border, delete the line:

outline-offset: -10px;

Comment: I want the white space, but Internet Explorer is not showing any.